# Conversion php form to SMTP

Tags: javascript, php, smtp

Could you take a look and tell me if my conversion is all right?

Old PHP:

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['message']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
echo json_encode(array('error'=>'true'));
return false;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$subject = ($_POST['subject'] ? $_POST['subject'] : "Website Contact   Form:  $name");



// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'email@to.com.br';// Add your email address inbetween the ''  replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = $subject;
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website   contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nLast Name:     $lastname\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone:  $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
echo json_encode(array('success'=>'true'));
return true;            
?>
```

New PHP:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
require("phpmailer/class.smtp.php");

// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) ||   empty($_POST['message']) ||     !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
echo json_encode(array('error'=>'true'));
return false;
}

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Usar autenticação SMTP (obrigatório para smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
$mail->Username = 'leadsvw@grupomenegalli.com.br'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP (endereço de email)
$mail->Password = '*********'; // Senha do servidor SMTP (senha do email usado)

$mail->From = "leadsvw@grupomenegalli.com.br"; // Seu e-mail
$mail->Sender = "leadsvw@grupomenegalli.com.br"; // Seu e-mail
$mail->FromName = "Dimasa VW"; // Seu nome

$mail->AddAddress('leadsvw@grupomenegalli.com.br', 'Dimasa');

$mail->IsHTML(true);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$mail->Subject = "Contato a partir do site Dimasa VW";

$message = "
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Contato a partir do site Dimasa VW</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <p>
            Nome: $name<br>

            Email: $email_address<br>

            Telefone: $phone<br>

            Mensagem: $message
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
";

$mail->Body = $message;
$xx = $mail->Send();

$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();

if($xx){
echo json_encode(array('success'=>'true'));
return true;
}           
?>
```

The script is the same for both:

```
$(function() {
$("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
preventSubmit: true,
submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
    // additional error messages or events
},
submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
    // get values from FORM
    var topic = $("select#user-topic").val();
    var name = $("input#user-name").val();
    var email = $("input#user-email").val();
    var phone = $("input#user-phone").val();
    var message = $("textarea#user-message").val();
    var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
    // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
    if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
        firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../mail/contact_me.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            topic: topic,
            name: name,
            email: email,
            phone: phone,
            message: message
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.error){
                // Fail message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;").append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<span>Perdão " + firstName + ", parece que ocorreu uma falha no envio, tente novamente!</span>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            }
            else if(data.success){
                // Success message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;").append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').append("<span>Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso </span>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').append('</div>');
                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            }
        }
    })
},
filter: function() {
    return $(this).is(":visible");
},
});
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

I not have a great understanding of php, if there are any errors, please tell me. If i need to change the script for the new php, what i should change?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There is an error displayed in your code? I don't understand...

Comment: What kind of question is that? What do you expect we should answer?

Comment: the server of the client does not send email without authentication

Comment: I hope you tell if the new php is right